# Numbers are not adding correctly in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

So I want to make a basic calculator, and I am having trouble,

```
Public Class Form1
Private Numb1
Private Oper
Private Numb2
Private Start As Boolean
Private Ans 
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Numb1 = TextBox1.Text
    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox2.Text = Numb1 + "+"
    Oper = 1
    Start = True
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Numb2 = TextBox1.Text
    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox2.AppendText(Numb2)
    If Oper = 1 Then
        Ans = Numb1 + Numb2
        TextBox1.Text = Ans
    ElseIf Oper = 2 Then
        Ans = Numb1 - Numb2
    End If
    Start = False
End Sub
```

So the problem is that when I add 1 + 2 using the calculator, it comes out to 12, instead of 3. I don't know what to do for it to realize i dont want the numbers next to eachother, I want them added.

Comment: That,s because the type of TextBox.Text is String... "adding" strings together concatenates them

Comment: So it should be `val(textbox1.text) = numb1`?

Comment: First of all, not declaring the type of your variables, even though VB.NET will allow for this, is a bad practice in my opinion. You should enable OPTION STRICT ON in your project's properties, at least until you understand what you're doing

Comment: As one last comment, in the hope you will see it as constructive, programming is not a guessing game. You see, computers, and also compilers, have a tendency to take things very literally, so they will do exactly what you tell them to do, based on the rules specific to the system you're dealing with. Stop guessing, start reading on the subject, start searching Google, but please don't try to outguess computers. You will more than likely fail.

Answer (score 3):

To add the numbers you need to convert the text to integer

```
Numb1 = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
```

As of now, you are `concatenating` string, hence the output.

Also, as of now your declaration of the variable is considered as an object, hence declare it as

```
Private Numb1 as Integer
```

Same for `Numb2`